# Alternative to Macbook air 11

Tags: laptop

I need to replace my trusty macbook air 11 because it's 7 years old and only has 2GB RAM but I'm struggling to find a replacement. I need enough power to run SQL server and Visual Studio and I'd rather go for a windows laptop (at the moment I'm dual-booting)

The problem is I'm reluctant to go any bigger than my current one - the dell XPS 13 seems much too large, but all the 11 inch windows laptops seem to be cheap and low-powered

It's for occasional "emergency" development and support purposes so doesn't have to be that powerful, but I think a cheap 11 inch one would only have a limited lifespan (both in terms of reliability and hardware spec) and I'd rather pay more for something that will get me through another 7 years.

TIA for any recommendations

Comment: The XPS 13 is only a tad larger than the MacBook Air–seriously, like half a pound and half an inch in the largest direction. Any other requirements? Battery life? Price? Screen size? Resolution? GPU? Webcam, mic? What size database are you dealing with? [The Visual Studio requirements are pretty low.](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-system-requirements-vs)

Comment: holy crap you're right! without measuring, It seemed so much bigger in the shop and I couldn't compare it directly because the air 11 isn't available any more. I'm going to go back and take another look at it.